# HTTP Post in angular 2 inserts only id but not remianing data in the JSON file

Tags: angular

I have a code in angular 2 that takes data from the user and attempts to insert it into JSON file using HTTP post request. But in my JSON file only id field gets added (in Incremental fashion) but the data is not hetting inserted.

Below is the function where newUserData contains a JSON record with certain data.

Please provide suggestions as to why data isn't getting written to the file.

```
addPeopleData(newUserData)
{
    let headers=new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    let options=new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
    let body=JSON.stringify(newUserData);
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/people',body,headers).subscribe((res:Response)=>res.json());
}
```

Comment: any error you getting in console ? while HTTP post ?

Comment: No. The console is clean without any errors

Comment: have you console logged newUserData, that it actually has more values than only the id?

Comment: yes. I did. The data is getting passed properly to the function and the variable newUserData has the necessary values in the right JSON format.